# What is $\lVert c \rVert_{X}$ where $c$ is constant?

Tags: banach-spaces

A thought just occurred to me, in a Banach space $X$, what is
$$\lVert c \rVert_{X}=c\lVert \text{Id} \rVert_{X}$$
where $c$ is a constant? Is it even defined?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. Is $c$ the linear map $X \to X$ that scales everything by $c$? Then its norm is $c$.

Comment: @nik No $c \in \mathbb{R}$. It is in the field of the Banach space.

Comment: There is a natural continuous injection from the field $k$ into the Banach space $X$ by identifying $c$ and $1.c$.

Comment: @user40276 But what is $1$ in a Banach space??

Comment: You assumed $Id$ in the Banach space, so in your notation $1 = Id$

Comment: @user40276 But does it always exist? I understand that the element $0$ exists cause it's a vector space. $0$ is the identity element under addition. But I am not sure that there is an identity element under multiplication if you know what I mean.

Comment: No. To use multiplication properly you must have a Banach algebra and even in this case 1 could not exist

Comment: @user40276 Right, so it is not defined.

Comment: Where did you run into this notation? Some context might help figuring out what is meant.